# TFS Areas, Optimal Definition and Configuration

Tags: tfs

Having recently migrated to TFS 2010 I was wondering what the best or most widely accepted definition or configuration is for an Area?

The only useful article I can find online is [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattlind/archive/2007/01/08/what-is-the-definition-of-an-area-in-tfs.aspx) and is what I would have assumed to be correct. However it got me thinking if any of the following is indeed more widely accepted.

- Areas by business functionality
- Areas by technology
- Areas by system layer
- Areas by physical or geographical location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the product/project you 're building, I suppose it was made available as a general-purpose placeholder which can get its meaning from the context of the team & the team mission.
I can imagine projects, where ignoring it on the grand total, would also be a perfectly acceptable solution.
Our initial TeamProject structure in fact did ignore Areas for our flagship product we construct in a Team Collection. This resulted in a reporting nightmare, since we needed it on a platform-level (TeamCollection), rather than a distinct part of it (Team Project). When we realized the problem, we went searching & found [this](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/when-should-i-use-areas-in-tfs-instead-of-team-projects-in-team-foundation-server-2010/) article, which made us change course: we are now using TFS Areas within one single Team Project & found what fitted best to our situation. 
In our universe Area = a distinct release line within the platform.

Comment: This might also be an interesting read on the matter: http://blog.hinshelwood.com/project-of-projects-with-team-foundation-server-2010/

Comment: both links really helped me come to a sensible conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

*Areas* in my opinion is a grouping mechanism, with *Areas* you can group your wortitems in any kind you want.

I think everything which fits to your development process and or make you more productive is ok.

All of your items on the list are valid types of areas, I saw all of them in projects.

But too deep hierarchies are not really helpfull, because if you create a workitem you than you have to choose/select the right area.

Comment: +1: balancing your Areas so they 're not unnecessary deep, eventually pays out on the long run.